# Low tolerance to newbies?

Tags: discussion, flags, down-votes, new-users, low-quality-posts

I understand this has been asked before, as per search, but none of the other questions tried to engage [in my opinion] and provide an actual solution.

**The Problem:**

Lately, I've been feeling completely unwelcomed to the community of Stack Overflow, it seems as if questions that are deemed as "stupid" or "couldn't you just look up documentation" are down-voted.

**The Specifics:**

Just recently a pretty popular guy who obviously knew his stuff went super passive-aggressive on me with "[Just do X]?", I was trying to explain to him how to me, this is new and I don't have as much experience as him. Unfortunately, I see this is a recurring thing.

**A suggestion:**
Now, surely, a question should have:

1. Good structure, name the problem, what you tried and what you think of as a solution.
2. Be clear about it, don't add unecessary words, just precisely what is needed.
3. Give an example, if you can. These help a lot.
4. If it's about code, post what you have so far.

There are plenty of questions that seem to follow these points and don't seem to be duplicates.

The search function is not perfect, therefore, we can't expect everyone to find their answers right away, just as I didn't myself on some questions.

If you think about it, they're low-quality, unfortunately, there's no clear distinction between stupid and simply being a newbie, in the community's eyes. I don't think most of them should be down-voted, instead...

**The Solution:**

My proposal is, if you think something's of low quality and I believe most people are mentally capable to distinct from trolling / straight-up low effort, just offer some improvements, link to another question and, well, do your part. That user will continue to ask questions the way he's done, if he's not told that's not the best way to do it, resulting in a ban, usually and a feeling of anxiety towards asking questions.

Obviously, I want to start a healthy discussion as to why this is happening, but can't help to say: We've all been there, give others a break, why is this happening and what can we do?

Comment: @rene I meant it as "I'm not as experienced as him", therefore, he should understand that for me, things don't flow as fast as they do for him. Edited.

Comment: I don't see *Just do X* as passive-aggresive. It is just to give someone who seems to be capable to work out the details a nudge in to the right direction. I leave that kind of comments if I don't have the time to write a proper answer. Just assume good faith when people leave comments.

Comment: @Dan _"... and don't seem to be duplicate ..."_  As for Stack Overflow, most of these questions actually are. It's not that the question states exactly the same problem, but the answers will point out how to solve it. Ideally in some generic way.

Comment: @rene Surely I did. It's a skill, unfortunately. I fancy fast & efficient typing, such as "Okay." instead of "Ha, nice!", though, this costs and it costs a lot. It puts off most people and please do believe my anectode, it hurts. Us humans are trained to speak in an engaging way, otherwise it's seen as disinterest. His answers were blunt and direct, but I took precisely only what he said and got my answer, but I still got the feeling of "ugh, why are you mean to me" and, unless trained, people respond badly to it. This seems to occur a lot.

Comment: @rene Agreed. Think about the _lack of debugging efforts_, and the often responded _"I don't know how to use the debugger."_. Most of these guys and gals misconcept Stack Overflow should be their personal (hoework) helpdesk.

Comment: @Dan Why would we want to have people around, that aren't skilled enough to even state their problem precisely, and being able to present their own research efforts reasonably and concisely?

Comment: *"questions that are deemed as "stupid" or "couldn't you just look up documentation" are down-voted"* - that's what's supposed to happen, though. Questions that aren't useful to other people or could be answered by doing the research that's required before asking questions on every site in this network *should* get downvoted.

Comment: Keep in mind that the SE network is build around content, not around people. Your feelings are not our problem. SO is not a social network site. Facebook does the thumbs up, on SO we only share knowledge by answering quality questions.  This is blunt and direct. But don't call me mean, because I'm not.

Comment: How is "just do X" passive aggressive? I mean, it could be, but it's more likely just someone trying to help. Downvotes and close votes etc are absolutely not an attack on "newbies" or a punishment or anything to be taken personally, they are literally what is telling the asker that the post needs improving, they are doing exactly what your solution says

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601)

Answer (score 9):

Oddly enough, the exact same thing came up on my the site I moderate at *today* and many of the points I made there are just as valid here.

I'd start by stating - the downvote popup reads the same everywhere -

> This question does not show research effort; it is unclear

Which dovetails very nicely with

> Lately, I've been feeling completely unwelcomed to the community of Stack Overflow, it seems as if questions that are deemed as "stupid" or "couldn't you just look up documentation" are down-voted.

It's also worth remembering *nearly everyone started off as a newbie*. Some of my old questions are cringe inducing. People complained (very very nicely) about my spelling and grammar. I didn't go "I'm a newbie, gimme a break" - I took the advice, passive aggressive or otherwise and *improved* my questions.

After 7 years, I still have people who make me go "Man, I wish I knew as much as he did".

> If you think about it, they're low-quality, unfortunately, there's no clear distinction between stupid and simply being a newbie, in the community's eyes. I don't think most of them should be down-voted, instead...

Of course, that also builds bad habits. Consistency in metamoderation means "But *he* didn't get punished for that. And when someone comments - they clearly are spending time and energy for no tangible or intangible benefit to try to help you.

> Just recently a pretty popular guy who obviously knew his stuff went super passive-aggressive on me with "[Just do X]?"

Did you? I mean, comments aren't meant for full answers but sometimes they're enough to nudge you in the right direction.

> The search function is not perfect, therefore, we can't expect everyone to find their answers right away, just as I didn't myself on some questions.

I'll grant you that, but SO's pretty high up on google. Google *is* a decent search engine, right?

Its also worth remembering with a few exceptions - the users who produce the most value are the ones looking for *hard* questions. A flood of people help vampiring may drive them off which is bad.

> My proposal is, if you think something's of low quality and I believe most people are mentally capable to distinct from trolling / straight-up low effort, just offer some improvements, link to another question and, well, do your part. That user will continue to ask questions the way he's done, if he's not told that's not the best way to do it, resulting in a ban, usually and a feeling of anxiety towards asking questions.

I do that a lot. To the point where I can type out "Welcome to superuser, We're not a forum, and things are done differently here. You may want to read the [help] and [tour] to get a better idea of how things work here"... in my sleep. Putting stuff that *needs* to be put on hold and downvoted to be downvoted however helps keep the *rest* of the site in better nick.

I'd note the *only* difference between a new user and a experienced user in the same situation is the experienced user gets reminded he should know better.